# Binding script to udev for creating a link to /run/user

Tags: linux, script, udev, mtp

I'm trying to create a link to the mtp folder in the /run/user/$UID/gvfs/ folder. I've wrote a script to do to, including some lines to test if the script is running properly. I binded to udev with a rule on /etc/udev/rules.d.
The script works properly when I run it with my normal user, but did not work when working as root (not permission!!). I've been trying to execute the script as a regular user (using sudo -u user, su user, runuser user...) But nothing works! I've check on the log file that the script is in deed running, but has no user and creates a malfunctioning link.

Any idea??

/etc/udev/rules.d/85-automount.rules:

```
ACTION=="add",SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8",ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", RUN+="sudo -u sphere /usr/local/bin/android_mount"
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="/home/sphere/log/android_mount.log"

i=1
for mtp_folder in $( ls -d /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp*); 
do
# Remove previous link
rm -f "/media/sphere/mtp$i"

# Create new link
OUT=$(ln -s $mtp_folder /media/sphere/mtp$i 2>&1)

# Notify error
if [[ -z $OUT ]]; then
    echo "$(date) - $OUT" >> $LOGFILE
fi
i=$(($i+1))
done
echo "$(date) - Script executed as user=$USER" >> $LOGFILE
```

Comment: Do you mean the udev rule doesn't have permission to run sudo, or the script has no permission while running as/with sudo? Why don't you add some debugging to the log, and/or add some verbosity with `-v` for `ln`. And some `id` & `ls` to see who & what's readable/writeable.

Answer (score 1):

I can take a guess at the problem: By using an udev rule, your script runs before the gvfs layer even sees the device, much less has a chance to automount it.

The idea of udev is that it first receives "uevents" from kernel, processes them according to rules, then rebroadcasts them to all other programs. (While other apps *can* also receive those events directly, it's rarely done, as processed ones have much more information and are guaranteed to be sent only when the device is *ready for use*.)

In other words, gvfs doesn't even get informed about the device until *after* your script runs.

And if you want to do something after gvfs mounts it, you'll have to react to events *gvfs* sends. Instead of a udev rule, you'll need a script that uses D-Bus and listens for signals on the session bus. Start with `dbus-monitor --session` or `busctl monitor --user` to find out what is sent, then use Perl's or Python's D-Bus modules to handle it.

---

As a side note, instead of `for var in $(ls -d /some/path*)`, you can get the same result by using just `for var in /some/path*`. It's not ls that expands wildcards – it's the shell itself.